# How to retrieve and insert data into database using a single url mapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

i am using Spring REST and hibernate and i want retrieve and update data into database on a single url mapping. I am retrieving a column data and after sum that data i want to update that data into another table but unable to update.

Here is my **DAO** class

```
    public List<Post> getPostList() throws Exception {
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.sum("val"));
    projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"));
    cr.setProjection(projList);
    List postList = cr.list();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return postList;
}
```

Here is my Entity class **Post.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Post implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="uid")
private long userId;

@Column(name="value")
private long val;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public long getVal() {
    return val;
}

public void setVal(long val) {
    this.val = val;
}

}
```

Here is my REST Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/posts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Post> getEmployee() {

    List<Post> postList = null;
    try {
        postList = profileService.getPostList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return postList;
}
```

I want to retrieve and update the data using single url..Please suggest me